# Need advice on .NET webservice method from Android application

Tags: android

I am accessing **.NET webservice methods from my Android application** using Java SOAP jar. 
I am getting response for a specific webservice method as an array .
Do we have an API within the Java SOAP library to convert the response from array to XML(String) ?

Also , since using the **external SOAP jar is around 90 KB in size** , would like to know of an alternative approach by which we can access webservice , maybe a **RESTful Web Services implementation** or anything of a similar type, which wont require to add an external jar to the Android application & hence **reduce the application size**.

It would be nice if someone can come up with the changes to be done on the server end for implementing the **RESTful WebServices in .NET & the client code for the same which I think will be only a HTTP connection .**

Kindly provide your valuable **comments/code snippet**s on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "KSoap2" it is leightweight and it is open source so you add just the libraries to your project and you can implement your method returning pure XML.

http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/